# IBM SPSS Statistics showing this error "There is label already defined for this value. Replace the existing label?"

Tags: statistics, spss

Hello everyone so I'm using IBM SPSS Statistics Verion 26 and set of data values that some of it does have same value but different labels and unfortunately its showing this dialog error. Can anyone help solve this issue please, thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIqYx.png)

i have already tied searching for solutions to this one but i cant find any fix for it maybe somebody knows this.

Comment: You just can't give more than one label to the same value, that would contradict the whole point of value labels. Say you analyse the frequency of jobPosition, and the value 5 appears 30 times - what should be reported, 30 Rad Techs or 30 Accountants?